# Open url on Facebook app or Facebook on browser

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game for Android on Unity (C#), when I click on a certain window I want the users to be redirected to facebook page. I already did it to open on the default android browser, but I would like to check if they have fb app open the page on the app if not open it on the browser.

I've tried the fb:

Application.OpenURL("fb://page/382171845278904");

This will open the app but won't go to the page, and I have no idea how to check if they have the app installed or not ..

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by checking if the user has facebook installed

```
try{
    ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0 );
    Application.OpenURL("fb://page/382171845278904");
} catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
    Application.OpenURL("http://facebook.com/382171845278904");
}
```

Comment: I could do it by a code I found .. just that fb app wont see page tabs .. so i left application.OpenURL("fbpage") .. but thanks i had a code similar to yours, i also had to use fb://profile/"id" instead of page .. page just opened the app but not the page .. 

thank you !!!